# Terraform:Snowflake:Dynamic Schema//Table/Database

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement:  Need to assign the value in var. select for database_name, schema_name, and table_name

I want to grant each table_name  to the share_name

Issue :

```
│   19:   dynamic "schema_name" {
│
│ Blocks of type "schema_name" are not expected here.
```

**Code:** Below is what I wrote but unable to fix the issue

```
resource "snowflake_table_grant" "grant" {
  for_each = var.select

  database_name = each.key

  dynamic "schema_name" {
    for_each = each.value
    content {
      schema_name = schema_name.key

      dynamic "table_name" {
        for_each = schema_name.value
        content {
          table_name = table_name.value

          privilege         = "SELECT"
          roles             = ["role1"]
          shares            = ["share1"]
          on_future         = false
          with_grant_option = false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "select" {
  type    = map(map(list(string)))
  default = {
    database1 = {
      schema1 = ["table1", "table2"],
      schema2 = ["table3", "table4"],
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: If you check [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/table_grant) you will see that there is no such thing as `schema` in `snowflake_table_grant`. Thus, what's exactly is your issue? Did you check the docs?

Comment: in the docs there is mention of `schema_name = `

Comment: Yes, `schema_name`  is different then `schema`. I would suggest checking the docs for valid attributes, and editing the question explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to assign value from the variable `select` for each database_name , schema_name and table_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your variable:

```
locals {

  select_flat = merge(flatten([
    for database_name, schemas in var.select: [
      for schema_name, tables in schemas: {
          for table_name in tables: 
            "${database_name}-${schema_name}-${table_name}" => {
                 "database_name" = database_name
                 "schema_name" = schema_name
                 "table_name" = table_name
             }                 
      }
    ] 
  ])...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "snowflake_table_grant" "grant" {
    for_each      = local.select_flat

    database_name = each.value.database_name
    schema_name   = each.value.database_name
    table_name    = each.value.table_name  

    privilege         = "SELECT"
    roles             = ["role1"]
    shares            = ["share1"]
    on_future         = false
    with_grant_option = false
}
```

Comment: Got below Error `Conflicting configuration arguments

on_future         = false │ "on_future": conflicts with shares`

Comment: @Kar `on_future` issues seems as a new one. Maybe you misconfured your databases? dots change `merge([a,b,c]...)` into `merge(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Hi @Marcin Looks like `snowflake_table_grant` will be deprecated as per Terraform warnings .. Need to use `snowflake_grant_privileges_to_role` Can you please update and provide how to provide table grants to the share with mentioned resource thanks

Comment: @Kar I would suggest making new SO question for the new issue.